# How to get line number information from XMLBeans' XMLError

Tags: java, xmlbeans

The subject basically says it all.

`XmlBeans'` `XmlError.getLine()` always returns -1.

Is there any way to get at least an approximate position for an error?

I have already tried the `XmlObject`, but since whitespace, quotes, et al. are stripped or changed, that's not much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation suggests you can do this by providing [XmlOptions](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setLoadLineNumbers()):

> **setLoadLineNumbers**
>
> If this option is set, line number
>   annotations are placed in the store
>   when parsing a document. This is
>   particularly useful when you want
>   XmlError objects to contain line
>   numbers. Note: This adds line numbers
>   info only for start tags. For line
>   number info on end tags use:
>   setLoadLineNumbers(java.lang.String)
>   Example:
>   xmlOptions.setLoadLineNumbers(XmlOptions.LOAD_LINE_NUMBERS_END_ELEMENT)